# how to add conditions for regular expression?

Tags: javascript, java, regex, string, regular-language

I have to get the string which start with `="` and ends with next `"`. But it should contains `<` symbol.

```
(="([^"])*<*")
```

String:

```
dit niet "dit wel" dit ook niet ="maar <dit ""en""dit ook"
REM dit niet "dit <wel" dit ook niet ="maar dit ""en""dit ook"
dit niet "dit wel" REM "maar dit ""en""dit ook"
```

The above code give me two string, I need to get only one mentioned below.

Expected Result:

```
="maar <dit "
```

Actual Result:

```
="maar <dit "
="maar dit "
```

NOTE:
Need to get all the results which start with `="` and have `<` and ends with next occurrence of `"`

Answer (score 3):

Your `="([^"])*<*"` regex matches `="`, then it captures any character other than `"` *repeatedly* (so that only the last occurrence of it is saved in the Group 1 buffer), and then *zero or more `<` symbols* followed with `"`. So, your regex does not really *require* a `<` to be present in the string you match.

You may use

```
="([^"<]*<[^"]*)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sT5hL6/2)

*Details*:

- `="` - a `="` sequence
- `([^"<]*<[^"]*)` - Group 1 that will hold the value:

  - `[^"<]*` - zero or more chars other than `"` and `<`
  - `<` - a `<` symbol
  - `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`
- `"` -  a double quote

Comment: If you care about unnecessary backtracking, you should consider using `*+` rather than `*`. While your answer avoids backtracking in the matching case, the engine might waste time in the non-matching case, searching for characters at place impossible to contain them.

Comment: @Holger JS regex does not support possessive quantifiers.

Comment: Ok, the question is tagged with `[javascript]` *and* `[java]`, that raised some confusion. I think, the OP should decide for one of them…

Comment: Yes, when there are two engines to support, the pattern should be supported by the least powerful one :(

Answer (score 2):

Switch your regex to

```
(="([^"]*<[^"]*)*")
```

Live [here](https://regex101.com/r/lD5vU6/1)

This part `([^"]*<[^"]*)` ensure that your inner string will contain `<`

Comment: There is some unnecessary backtracking your first `[^"]*` causes since it also matches `<`. See my answer how the pattern can be streamlined.